# How to rename unnamed columns in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tabula

I have a pdf with a table in it, and trying to get that table into Pandas. Extracting pdf tables is notoriously difficult to get right, but I have found tabula works best. It is far and away the best I have seen, though still not perfect. I have this pdf table:

[image: Table]

Note the headers of the table, and how they sometimes run onto the next row, and are generally not nice. I am prefacing the real problem, because all of the solutions I can see call for a better approach to creating the dataframe in the first place. This dataframe is the best I could get, but if you know how to get a better one out of tabula, please let me know.

I use tabula-py, and run this code:

```
holdingsDF = tbla.read_pdf(fileName, nospreadsheet=True)
```

There are many options, and I am not aware of all of them, but this seems to be the best I can do, after fiddling with the options. And the resulting DF is this:

```
         Unnamed: 0                  Unnamed: 1      Unnamed: 2 Identifier Unnamed: 4 Curren Unnamed: 6 TAG0 Strategy  
0        Asset Type                        Name      Identifier        NaN   Quantity    NaN      Price           NaN  
1               NaN                         NaN             NaN       Type        NaN     cy        NaN          Name  
2            Equity     Akamai Technologies Inc  AKAM US Equity     TICKER    (5,830)    USD     65.000          AKAM   
3  Convertible Bond             AKAM 0 02/15/19    US00971TAG67       ISIN  1,595,000    USD    100.875          AKAM   
4            Equity  Advanced Micro Devices Inc   AMD US Equity     TICKER  (181,500)    USD     13.490           AMD  
5  Convertible Bond          AMD 2 1/8 09/01/26    US007903BD80       ISIN  1,650,000    USD    185.500           AMD
```

If you look, you can see the header has been sort of split amongst the first three rows. How do I fix this? Are there any clever, elegant solutions to take the 'best' of the three names for each column, and make that the column name?

Thanks!!

Comment: Just type all the column names, it might be even faster than coming up with a programatic solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pure pandas solution - assuming the dataframe is read exactly as pasted below.

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('Unnamed.*', '') + \
             df.iloc[0].fillna('') + \
             df.iloc[1].fillna('')

df.drop([0,1], inplace=True)


1        Asset Type                        Name      Identifier  \
2            Equity     Akamai Technologies Inc  AKAM US Equity   
3  Convertible Bond             AKAM 0 02/15/19    US00971TAG67   
4            Equity  Advanced Micro Devices Inc   AMD US Equity   
5  Convertible Bond          AMD 2 1/8 09/01/26    US007903BD80   

1 IdentifierType   Quantity Currency    Price TAG0 StrategyName  
2         TICKER    (5,830)      USD   65.000              AKAM  
3           ISIN  1,595,000      USD  100.875              AKAM  
4         TICKER  (181,500)      USD   13.490               AMD  
5           ISIN  1,650,000      USD  185.500              None
```

Comment: I am getting a warning with this (Python 3.4, Pandas 0.16.2) `FutureWarning: using '+' to provide set union with Indexes is deprecated` I tried using 'union' but I get an error. Any help?

Comment: Upgrade to 0.19 or try putting .values at the end of all of them